# Loop keeps looping(corrected) - Recurring issue with the program exiting when not required

Tags: java

I have managed to correct most of the errors that were occurring.  The only issue that is now not working the way it should is the incrementing the event number when using menu item 1 and trying to add a new event to the array.  When I add an item it adds ok, but it overwrites what is already there, instead of taking the next slot after the last one, and then incrementing the event number by one.

```
package JavaEvent;

import java.util.Scanner;



import firstPrograms.My;
import firstPrograms.MyDate;
import firstPrograms.MyTime;

public class TestEvent 
{
public static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int noOfEvents = 25;  // number of stipulated events
    int opt = 0;
    boolean answer = false;

    Event [] allEvents = new Event [noOfEvents];

    allEvents[0] = new Event (1000, "West Ham United v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (9, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (9, 04, 2016), new MyTime (12, 45, 00), "Upton Park", 3500, 3498, 65.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[1] = new Event (1001, "Sunderland v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (24, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (24, 04, 2016), new MyTime (14, 05, 00), "Stadium of Light", 500, 500, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[2] = new Event (1002, "Arsenal v Crystal Palace", "Premiership", new MyDate (17, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (17, 04, 2016), new MyTime (16, 05, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 100, 98, 125.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[3] = new Event (1003,"Arsenal v West Bromwich Albion", "Premiership", new MyDate (21, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (21, 04, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 125, 72, 95.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[4] = new Event (1004, "Arsenal v Norwich City", "Premiership", new MyDate (30, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (30, 04, 2016), new MyTime (17, 30, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 1250, 1137, 110, 0.025);
    allEvents[5] = new Event (1005, "Manchester City v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (8, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (8, 05, 2016), new MyTime (16, 05, 00), "Etihad Stadium", 5000, 4796, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[6] = new Event (1006, "Arsenal v Aston Villa", "Premiership", new MyDate (15, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (15, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 30, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 1250, 872, 16.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[7] = new Event (1007, "MLS All-Stars v Arsenal", "Friendly", new MyDate (28, 01, 2016),  new MyDate (28, 07, 2016), new MyTime (17, 00, 00), "Avaya Stadium", 500, 391, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[8] = new Event (1008, "Chivas de Guadalajara v Arsenal", "Friendly", new MyDate (31, 01, 2016),  new MyDate (31, 07, 2016), new MyTime (19, 30, 00), "StubHub Center", 1250, 872, 16.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[9] = new Event (1009, "West Ham United v Manchester United", "Cup", new MyDate (13, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (13, 04, 2016), new MyTime (19, 00, 00), "Upton Park", 750, 615, 85.00, 0.075);
    allEvents[10] = new Event (1010, "Everton v Manchester United", "Cup", new MyDate (14, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (23, 04, 2016), new MyTime (17, 15, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 10000, 5000, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[11] = new Event (1011, "Crystal Palace v Watford", "Cup", new MyDate (24, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (24, 04, 2016), new MyTime (16, 00, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 10000, 10000, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[12] = new Event (1012, "FA Cup Final - TBC", "Cup", new MyDate (25, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (21, 05, 2016), new MyTime (15, 00, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 20000, 0, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[13] = new Event (1013, "UEFA Champions League Final - TBC", "Europe", new MyDate (5, 5, 2016),  new MyDate (28, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "Stadio Giuseppe Meazza", 25000, 0, 350.00, 0.01);
    allEvents[14] = new Event (1014, "UEFA Europa League Final - TBC", "Europe", new MyDate (6, 05, 2016),  new MyDate (18, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "St. Jakob-Park", 20000, 0, 250.00, 0.015);

    do
    {
        Event.mainMenu("Event Menu"); // Calls the main menu
        opt = Event.option(1, 6); // sets the validation of the numbers entered by the user in the menu

        switch (opt)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                    System.out.println("\nAdd Events:");

                    int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
                    MyDate tempSaleDate;
                    MyDate tempEventDate;
                    int hour = 0, mins = 0, secs = 0;
                    MyTime tempTime;
                    String keyedAnswer = "";
                    int tempEventNo = 0;
                    //boolean answer = false;


                    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                    {       
                        //if (allEvents[i] != null)
                        //{
                            if (tempEventNo == allEvents[i].getEventNo())
                            {
                                tempEventNo += i++;
                            }
                            //else
                            //tempEventNo = allEvents[i].getEventNo()+1;
                            //events[size].setEventNo(events[size-1].getEventNo() + 1);


                            allEvents[i] = new Event();

                            allEvents[i].setEventNo(tempEventNo);

                            //allEvents[i].setEventNo((allEvents[i].getEventNo() + 1));

                            System.out.println("\n\tPlease enter name of event: ");
                            allEvents[i].setEventName(key.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's category: ");
                            allEvents[i].setCategory(key.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter event location: ");
                            allEvents[i].setVenue(key.nextLine());
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets date of sale (ie 1 - 31): ");
                            day = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets month of sale (ie 1 - 12): ");
                            month = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets year of sale (ie 2016): ");
                            year = key.nextInt();
                            tempSaleDate =  new MyDate(day, month, year);
                            allEvents[i].setDateOnSale(tempSaleDate);
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's date of event (ie 1 - 31): ");
                            day = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's month of event (ie 1 - 12): ");
                            month = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's year of event (ie 2016): ");
                            year = key.nextInt();
                            tempEventDate = new MyDate(day, month, year);
                            allEvents[i].setEventDate(tempEventDate);
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's start hour (ie 1am = 1, 10am = 10, 10pm = 22, etc): ");
                            hour = key.nextInt(); 
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's  start minutes (ie = 00, 15, 30, 45, etc): ");
                            mins = key.nextInt();
                            key.nextLine();
                            tempTime = new MyTime(hour, mins, secs);
                            allEvents[i].setEventTime(tempTime);
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket allocation: ");
                            allEvents[i].setTicketsReceived(key.nextInt());
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the amount of tickets sold for the event: ");                    
                            allEvents[i].setTicketsSold(key.nextInt());
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket cost: £");
                            allEvents[i].setTicketCost(key.nextDouble());
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket commission rate: ");
                            allEvents[i].setCommissionRate(key.nextDouble());
                            key.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("\n\t\tWould you like to add another event (Y / N): ");
                            keyedAnswer = key.nextLine();

                            if (keyedAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                            {
                                answer = false;
                                break;
                            //continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                answer = true;
                            //continue;
                            }
                        //}
                }

            }
            break;


            case 2: 
            {
                Event.headersEventNo();
                for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                {
                    if (allEvents[i] != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(allEvents[i].toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            case 3:
            {       
                do
                {
                    Event.searchMenu("Search Menu"); // Calls the search menu
                    opt = Event.option(1, 4); // sets the validation of the numbers entered by the user in the menu

                    int tempEventNo = 0;
                    int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
                    MyDate tempEventDate;
                    String tempEventCat = "";

                    switch (opt)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please enter the event no: ");
                            tempEventNo = key.nextInt();
                            key.nextLine();

                            for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (allEvents[i] != null)
                                {
                                    if (tempEventNo != allEvents[i].getEventNo())
                                    {
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                    else if (tempEventNo == allEvents[i].getEventNo())
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("\t" + allEvents[i]);//break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        {
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's date of event (ie 1 - 31): ");
                            day = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's month of event (ie 1 - 12): ");
                            month = key.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's year of event (ie 2016): ");
                            year = key.nextInt();
                            tempEventDate = new MyDate(day, month, year);
                            key.nextLine();

                            for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (allEvents[i] != null)
                                {
                                    if (!tempEventDate.toShortDate().equals(allEvents[i].eventDate.toShortDate()))
                                    {
                                        i++;
                                        //System.out.println("\t\t" + tempEventDate.toShortDate());
                                        //System.out.println("\t\t" + allEvents[i]);
                                        //break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //System.out.println("\t\tNo Events On This Date - " + tempEventDate.toShortDate());
                                        System.out.println("\t\t" + allEvents[i]);
                                        //break;
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        {
                            System.out.println("Please enter the event category: ");
                            tempEventCat = key.nextLine();

                            for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (allEvents[i] != null)
                                {
                                //if (tempEventCat != allEvents[i].getCategory())
                                    if (!tempEventCat.equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                    System.out.println("\t" + allEvents[i]);
                                }
                                else //if (tempEventCat.equals(allEvents[i].getCategory())}
                                {
                                    //i++;


                                    System.out.println("\t" + allEvents[i]);
                                    //break;
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                        case 4:

                        break;
                    }
                }while (opt != 4);
            }
            break;

            case 4:
            {
                Event.headersEventIncome();

                for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                {
                    if (allEvents[i] != null)
                    {
                        System.out.printf("%-9s%-16d%-36s%s%-10.2f%s%.2f", "\n", allEvents[i].getEventNo(), allEvents[i].getEventName(), "\t\t£", allEvents[i].getActualIncome(), "\t\t£", allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome());
                    }
                }

            }
            break;

            case 5:
            {
                double tempPremActualIncome = 0.00, totalPremActTemp = 0.00;
                double tempPremPotentialIncome = 0.00, totalPremPotTemp = 0.00;
                double percentagePremAchieved = 0.00;
                double tempFriendlyActualIncome = 0.00, totalFriendlyActTemp = 0.00;
                double tempFriendlyPotentialIncome = 0.00, totalFriendlyPotTemp = 0.00;
                double percentageFriendlyAchieved = 0.00;
                double tempCupActualIncome = 0.00, totalCupActTemp = 0.00;
                double tempCupPotentialIncome = 0.00, totalCupPotTemp = 0.00;
                double percentageCupAchieved = 0.00;
                double tempEuroActualIncome = 0.00, totalEuroActTemp = 0.00;
                double tempEuroPotentialIncome = 0.00, totalEuroPotTemp = 0.00;
                double percentageEuroAchieved = 0.00;
                String tempCategory ="";

                System.out.println("\n\nIncome Per Category:");
                Event.headersCategoryIncome();

                for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                {
                    if(allEvents[i] != null)
                    {
                        if("Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
                        {
                            tempPremActualIncome = allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                            totalPremActTemp += tempPremActualIncome;
                            tempPremPotentialIncome = allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome();
                            totalPremPotTemp += tempPremPotentialIncome;
                            percentagePremAchieved = ((totalPremActTemp / totalPremPotTemp) * 100);
                            tempCategory = "Premiership";
                        }
                    }
                }

                    System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", totalPremActTemp, "\t\t\t\t£", totalPremPotTemp, "\t\t\t\t", percentagePremAchieved);

                for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(allEvents[i] != null)
                        {
                            if ("Cup".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
                            {
                                tempCupActualIncome = allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                                totalCupActTemp += tempCupActualIncome;
                                tempCupPotentialIncome = allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome();
                                totalCupPotTemp += tempCupPotentialIncome;
                                percentageCupAchieved = ((totalCupActTemp / totalCupPotTemp) * 100);
                                tempCategory = "Cup";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", totalCupActTemp, "\t\t\t\t£", totalCupPotTemp, "\t\t\t\t", percentageCupAchieved);

                    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(allEvents[i] != null)
                            if ("Friendly".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
                        {
                            tempFriendlyActualIncome = allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                            totalFriendlyActTemp += tempFriendlyActualIncome;
                            tempFriendlyPotentialIncome = allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome();
                            totalFriendlyPotTemp += tempFriendlyPotentialIncome;
                            percentageFriendlyAchieved = ((totalFriendlyActTemp / totalFriendlyPotTemp) * 100);
                            tempCategory = "Friendly";
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", totalFriendlyActTemp, "\t\t\t\t£", totalFriendlyPotTemp, "\t\t\t\t", percentageFriendlyAchieved);

                    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(allEvents[i] != null)
                            if ("Europe".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
                        {
                                tempEuroActualIncome = allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                                totalEuroActTemp += tempEuroActualIncome;
                                tempEuroPotentialIncome = allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome();
                                totalEuroPotTemp += tempEuroPotentialIncome;
                                percentageEuroAchieved = ((totalEuroActTemp / totalEuroPotTemp) * 100);
                                tempCategory = "Europe";
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", totalEuroActTemp, "\t\t\t\t£", totalEuroPotTemp, "\t\t\t\t", percentageEuroAchieved);
            }
            break;


            case 6:
            {
                My.p("\n\n\t\tGoodbye");
            }
            break;
        }

    }while (opt != 6);
}
```

}

Comment: 'where is allEvents ?

Comment: It loops infinitely because you are never removing anything from allEvents therefore the allEvents[i] will never equal null

Comment: You never change the value of `allEvents` inside the loop, so how would it ever become `null`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. This only loops while allEvents == null. If allEvents equalled null, then it would break inside the block. If it isn't null after coming out of the block, then it won't repeat, because it never gets set to null inside the block.

Comment: allEvents is the prepopulated array, it is initialised to 25 but there are only 15 entries into the array, so that is all I am trying to print.

Comment: Why do you need the while loop at all? Why not just loop through allEvents with the for loop and that's it? You can do a null check prior to doing so, if you need to.

Comment: If `allEvents == null`, then `allEvents[i]` would be a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ok so if I take out the do/while loop, and put the null check before the for loop like this:case 2:
{
 if(allEvents != null)
 Event.headersEventNo();
 for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
 {
  System.out.println(allEvents[i].toString()); 
 }
}
break;  I get a null pointer exception

Comment: Yeah, just `if (allEvents != null) { // for loop in here... }`. And you may not even need the null check, if your design ensures that it's non null at this stage.

Comment: You still need to check the elements inside the array for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this...

```
case 2:
    // You may not even require this check, if it's ensured to be non-null.
    if (allEvents != null) {
        Event.headersEventNo();
        for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
        {
            if (allEvents[i] != null)
            {
                System.out.println(allEvents[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }

    break;
```

You may be better off instantiating a List here though and simply looping through its contents. That way, you can avoid needless null checks.

Comment: I'd also get the event object prior to its null check and then just use a reference to that object (I don't know the type of your event objects inside allEvents. I'm assuming it's just Event, but that's a guess).

Comment: So when I try the piece of code above, I still get the same error it keeps looping endlessly

Comment: How can it loop endlessly? There's no infinite loop here. All I'm doing is moving through the entries in allEvents and outputting their values. It will come to an end when i == allEvents.length.

Comment: You may have an infinite loop inside your `Event.headersEventNo()` method, but you haven't given us that code. If you post the code for that method, I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: there are no loops in the Event.headersEventNo() it only contains the output to print the headers when called

Comment: Then it's not possible for this to loop endlessly. It will loop through the elements in the array and come to a halt. Your infinite loop must be outside this code block, above your switch statement or something. Because this code here can't loop endlessly. The only way to make a for loop infinitely loop is to affect the iterator `i` somewhere inside the loop. And I'm not doing that here.

Comment: I think this has corrected the issue, but think it may have opened up others :(

Comment: Oh well, glad I was able to help you at least partway on the road to a solution. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Only having one issue now with the item overwriting an event when adding instead of going to the last one and entering after it, and then incrementing the event number by 1 ie the last event in the array is 1014, the next one when added should be 1015.  Everything that I have tried just has me going round in circles.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at your code for adding new entries. Your index may be off by one or something in your checks.

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are right about your loop behaviour, You are doing nothing with `allEvents` so check some condition and Use Loop Jump Statements,

```
int i = 0;
looper: //Jump Statements
while(true){
     if(++i > 10)
          break looper;
     System.out.println("Value of i is : " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AllEvents will never be null (not even if you remove all elements of it). Null means unassigned, not empty.

Remove the outer do..while loop since it has no function, and effectively create the endless loop you are reporting :)

(On the long run, consider using List instead of an array which is not fully populated. Lists are much easier to work with and much safer too.)